# Is it possible to implement realtime paging(aac library) with room?

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-paging

Currently, I'm working on p2p messenger app. Our messages are storing inside room database. When we send or receive a new message we insert it in room db. And it works, method **onItemRangeInserted** from **RecyclerView.AdapterDataObserver** is triggered.

But, when the datasource riches the last page(fetch last data from db), method **onItemRangeInserted** is not called. Only after the second insert into db, this method is triggered.

We use default **PositionalDataSource** implemented by room and **LivePagedListBuilder**.

So, is it real to use it for real-time paging with room? If yes, then what could be the problem?

If need some code, please, let me know. Because there are a lot of code, and I'm not sure which part I should attach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set **setEnablePlaceholders** to **true** in **PagedList.Config** did the trick.

Answer (score 2):

Though I am not working on a real-time chat application but I think this [repo](https://github.com/anjandebnath/ArchitectureComponent/tree/RnD_chathistory) will help you and solve your problem.